# Examine the continuity of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

There is confusion regarding continuity of the following function. When solving in polar form it comes continuous but when solving in $x$ and $y$ then not continuous.

> Examine the continuity of
>
> $$f(z)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/z}&z\neq0\\0&z=0\end{cases}$$
>
> at $z=0$

Answer (score 1):

Check what happens as you approach $z=0$ using real and purely imaginary values, respectively. (You will see that that limit doesn't exist.)